# find ... | grep -ve ... | total filesize?

Tags: bash, grep, find

I'd like to get the total size of a large group of files, *minus* lotsa files I don't want. I can get the *paths* of the files I want with

```
find /path/to/filespace/ -type f | grep -ve '~$\|csv$\|eps$\|jpg$\|nc$\|ncf$\|pdf$\|png$\|tif$'
```

However what I *really* want is the total size of the files denoted by those paths. If I only wanted files with one particular extension, I could do [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323696/why-does-find-name-txt-xargs-du-hc-give-multiple-totals/1323786#1323786)

```
find . -name "*txt" -print0 | du -hc --files0-from=- | tail -n 1
```

but this has 2 problems for my actual usecase:

1. I want to *exclude* certain extensions, not include them
2. The above (and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134245/total-size-of-group-of-files-selected-with-find)) rely on `find -print0`, and I don't know how to make that work with `grep -ve`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think the `grep` is needed

```
find -type f \! -regex '.*\.\(csv\|eps\|jpg\|nc\|ncf\|pdf\|png\|tif\)$' -print0 | du -hc --files0-from=- | tail -n 1
```

Or without any `regex` (replace `...` with extensions)

```
find -type f \! \( -name  '*.csv' -o -name '*.eps' -o ... \) -print0 | du -hc --files0-from=- | tail -n 1
```

Comment: I bow to your superior command of `find`! First one works, second would be too much typing ...

Answer (score 0):

Answer to first question:

you can use `!` to exclude certain extension.
( Since some shell treats `!` as special character, you might have to surround it with `''`)

```
find . '!' -name "*.txt"
```

Answer to second question:

Gnu grep has `-z` option, so you can use it

```
find . -print0 | grep -vze "txt$" | du -hc --files0-from=- | tail -n 1
```

Comment: see following 'answer' regarding 'grep -z'

Answer (score 0):

Once again, the process of asking the question stimulates brain to find the answer. I think, what does `-print0` *do*, anyway? IIRC it converts newlines into 0-bytes. And I know how to do that, with `tr`:

```
find /path/to/filespace/ -type f | grep -ve '~$\|csv$\|eps$\|jpg$\|nc$\|ncf$\|pdf$\|png$\|tif$' | tr '\n' '\0' | du -hc --files0-from=- | tail -n 1
```

which works!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in Bash with globbing.

```
declare -a list
for f in *; do
    case "$f" in
        *.csv|*.eps|*.jpg|*.nc|*.ncf|*.pdf|*.png|*.tif) ;;
        *) list+=("$f");;
    esac
done
du -ch "${list[@]}" | tail -n 1
```